# Room DB with coroutines insert callback

Tags: android, android-room, deferred, kotlin-coroutines

I am using RoomDB with Coroutines. My code looks like below -

```
@Dao
interface AccountDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAccountData(accountModel: AccountModel)

    @Query("DELETE FROM accountTable")
    suspend fun deleteAccountData()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM accountTable")
    suspend fun getAccountData(): Deferred<AccountModel>
}
```

//From my class

```
override suspend fun retrieveAccountData(): AccountModel {
     return accountDao.getAccountData().await()
}
```

How do I return or what do I return for insert or delete from the DAO so that I know insert or delete was successful?

Comment: Have You read documentation https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert ? Insert by default returns rowId and delete returns number of deleted rows. You can modify Your declarations to return value and then check it.

Comment: Oh cool then I could use it for my LiveData

Answer (score 0):

If the `@Insert` method receives only 1 parameter, it can return a `Long`, which is the new rowId for the inserted item. If the parameter is an array or a collection, it should return `Long[]` or `List<Long>` instead.

`@Delete` method returns an `Int` indicating the number of rows removed from the database.

So, your `Dao` should be like following:

```
@Dao
interface AccountDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAccountData(accountModel: AccountModel): Long

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteAccountData(accountModel: AccountModel): Int

    @Query("SELECT * FROM accountTable")
    suspend fun getAccountData(): Deferred<AccountModel>
}
```